# is there a way to extrude a B&W 2d video into a 3d object?

Tags: modifiers, video, extrude, displacement, svg

I know you can do this with vector images and SVGs and extrude them to 3d, but I wanted to make a black and white video displace fluid and was wondering if I could use a black and white video to create a negative subtraction from the object (I.e if there were a black circle in the video I would have a cylinder in Blender and if it morphed into a square in the video I would have a cube in blender)

Comment: You can do that with geometry nodes using video as a texture, or you could use a video to displace geometry, but it will not delete parts of it then. As you would probably need quite dense geometry for any of this, it may be quite slow. It would be better if you provided some context. It may lead to an answer that is better suited for what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: replying to @Martynas Žiemys "It would be better if you provided some context. It may lead to an answer that is better suited for what you actually want to achieve."
I wanted to use a 2d video as a displacement for a fluid sim to have the water in the render be pushed around by the video, (you know the "bad apple" video? I need to make something in blender for a school project and thought that having that video but made as a fluid sim would be funny, so that the water would flow to the darker (or lighter, depending on what I want) parts of the video